# Jenkins publish over ssh plugin not getting the ansible tasks output

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsFbv.jpg)
1.Hi Team.

- i have a jenkins server i was configured a publish over ssh plugin in my jenkins server
- i have configured to the job using publish over ssh plugin configured to the ansible command.
- i am unable to get the output in the in my jenkins console output,
- if i manually run the command i am getting the tasks output, but when i build the job i am unable to
  get the tasks out put but that command is executing.

Comment: increase the ssh-timeout value https://www.tecmint.com/increase-ssh-connection-timeout/ and then try

Comment: hear i am unable to get the output of ansible command